# Is it possible to download m3u8 as separate files using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I know it is possible to download playlist and concatenate it on the fly with something like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tls,tcp" -i input.m3u8 -codec copy output.mp4
```

But I need to get all playlist files separated. Is there a ffmpeg option for that?

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: Is it ok to separate them after downloading as a single file?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood the question.

> Do you want to download each segment in the playlist as an mp4?

if you know the length of time of the segments, you could do**

```
ffmpeg -i  'https://example.com/hls/index.m3u8 \
-f segment -segment_time 10  -c copy  -y out%03d.mp4
```

just match the segment time.